# Disable iPhone - view only lock screen

Tags: ios, swift

Is there anyway in Swift to disable the iPhone or only allow certain features to be used when a certain condition is met?

for example:

```
if (phoneIsOnAndUnlocked == true){
    // some kind of command to disable or lock the device for a 
    //time or button is pressed

    Device.lockDevice = true

    if(homeButton.pressed.numberOfPresses == 2) {
        Device.lockDevice = false
    }
}
else {
    //Device is still running
}
```

Comment: No, can't be done with public APIs.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah I didn't think so